# how to manipulate cv::mat entity in structure in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, structure, mat

I have n images, after opencv operation each image will have its own mat file. I try to keep this in array of structure. My structure as follows:

```
struct _img_info {
    char name[40];
    Mat des;
} * img_info;
```

I can calculate the Mat temp, then try to its content in _img_info's des. however I get segmentation fault. My dump code like that:

```
img_info mydes = (img_info)malloc(sizeof(struct _img_info));
Mat fg2(2,3,CV_32F,2);
mydes->des = fg2.clone ();
cout << mydes->des << endl;
```

could you give me idea how to manipulate the Mat type in structure. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code how you try to set the des value and how you try to manipulate? Normally you could just do: your_img_info.des = temp.clone();

Comment: I am quite new at opencv, at first I try to ***_img_info.des = temp***, and this give segmentation fault. I will try your way.

Comment: @Micka I have tried your suggest on single structure and it works, however when I try to utilize it on structure pointer it give segmentation fault.

Comment: _img_info.des = temp can work too, but it will not copy the data so depending on what you do it might or might not work.

Comment: You should add a cout << fg2 << endl; right after creating your mat to see that your matrix creation was wrong. An I think you dont need the malloc there at all.

Answer (score 0):

#### careful here ! :

```
Mat fg2(2,3,CV_32F,2);
```

you probably expected, that the Mat would be initialized with Scalar(2), but instead it took the 2 as a (non-existing) **pointer** to external data ;(  [and it's probably the clone(), not the assignment, that crashed because of this]

instead use :

```
Mat fg2(2,3,CV_32F,Scalar(2.0)); // explicit value
// or even:
Matx23f fg2(2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0);
```

and you probably don't need the clone() in that case

also, since your struct contains a **c++ / RAII object**, please **do not use malloc / free , but new / delete**, else the Mat's destructor won't get called.